# Input checks in Haskell data constructors

Tags: haskell, constructor, validation

How can I add input checks to Haskell data constructors? Let's say I have

```
import Data.Time.Calendar

data SchedulePeriod = SchedulePeriod { startDate :: Day
    , endDate :: Day
    , accrualStart :: Day
    , accrualEnd :: Day
    , resetDate :: Day
    , paymentDate :: Day
    , fraction :: Double }
    deriving (Show)
```

and I want to impose a constraint `startDate < endDate`. Is there a way to do it without creating an abstract data type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a type with restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978191/how-to-make-a-type-with-restrictions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard way is to use a [smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) that checks the precondition before creating the value, and to not export the real constructor it uses. Of course, this is creating an abstract data type, as you said.

The only way to achieve this without a smart constructor would be *really* evil type-system hackery (and you wouldn't be able to use the standard `Day` type).

Comment: Can I use named parameters in smart constructors?

Comment: If you mean imitating record syntax, then unfortunately not. However, you could define another record to serve as the input to the smart constructor. That's probably only worth the duplication if your constructor does something more than validate the input, though (e.g. calculating auxiliary fields).

Comment: @quant_dev If the reason you don't want an abstract data type is so that you can pattern match on the constructors, you can do the dual of smart constructors and implement smart destructors (similar to `maybe` and `either`).

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez This sounds interesting, can you write more?

Answer (score 15):

Accept ehird's answer.  I'm just writing this so I can explain the smart destructors I mentioned in a comment and I can't fit the explanation in a comment.

Let's say that you have the type:

```
data T x y z = A | B x | C y z
```

ehird already explained how to abstract away the constructor, which is just to provide "smart" constructors.  Like you mentioned, this requires hiding the constructors and then you can't use them to pattern match.  However, you can solve this using a "smart" destructor, which is equivalent to pattern-matching against every possible constructor.

To explain this, let's first start with how we'd write a function of type T if the constructors were exposed:

```
myFunction :: T x y z -> d
myFunction t = case t of
    A     -> f1
    B x   -> f2 x
    C y z -> f3 y z
```

We know from the function's type signature that the types of `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` must be:

```
f1 :: d
f2 :: x -> d
f3 :: y -> z -> d
```

So if we were to generalize `myFunction` to be a smart destructor, we just pass `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` as parameters to it:

```
smartDestructor :: d -> (x -> d) -> (y -> z -> d) -> t -> d
smartDestructor f1 f2 f3 t = case t of
    A     -> f1
    B x   -> f2 x
    C y z -> f3 y z
```

So if you export `smartDestructor`, then people can basically pattern-match against your type without needing access to the constructors.

If you've ever used the `maybe` or `either` functions, before, then you've used a smart destructor, although in those cases the constructors are not hidden, so they are mainly provided as convenience functions:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe f1 f2 m = case m of
    Nothing -> f1
    Just  a -> f2 x

either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
either f1 f2 e = case e of
    Left  a -> f1 a
    Right b -> f2 b
```

In your case, the purpose of the smart destructor is just so you can hide the constructors and not expose the constructors.

Comment: @quant_dev I just learned that there is a better name for "smart destructors".  It's called "church encoding" the data type and it refers to the fact that any data type can be represented as a function, and this functional encoding is called "church encoding".  For a really good explanation, check out this link: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/nDNOvgzSRV6TNq8KhCgZ

Comment: Great answer, precisely what I needed! @GabrielGonzalez Given that your answer is almost 4 years old, are you aware of any newer mechanisms allowing one to be able to pattern match *and* to have smart constructors?

Comment: @PiotrJustyna Yes.  Liquid Haskell lets you do this in a much better way now.  See: https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/01-intro.html

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Interesting. Can these deconstructors be used as part of case ... of statements or is this something only the compiler can generate from data constructors? And if so how would they be used?

Comment: @dlouwers: Yes.  Haskell now supports this in the form of the `PatternSynonyms` extension now: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms