# Defining a new haskell type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to haskell. I've two questions but they're somewhat related.

Is it possible to define a type of Integers excluding specific integers for example zero. Or just positive numbers.

```
data allIntsButZero = ..? { a /= 0 | for all a in Int} ??
data positiveInts   = ..? { a >= 0 | for all a in Int} ??
```

In short, can I define a type as a subset of another type?

Secondly, can i define a type where there is a logic imposed? e.g.

```
type doublePair = (Int, Int * 2) {- where snd is always 2 times of fst -}
data validDDMMYYYY = G Int Int Int {- where complies to gregorian calendar -}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input checks in Haskell data constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161009/input-checks-in-haskell-data-constructors)

Comment: Please refrain from asking two questions at once. Your second question is answered by the Q&A linked above. The short answer to the subtyping question is "no, Haskell does not support subtyping". You could get around it with typeclasses, but then your question needs to be much more specific about how you *use* those types, instead of just what they *are*. There are some questions about it already on this website, and [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/423o0c/why_no_subtypingsubtype_polymorphism/) provides some good arguments why subtyping isn't part of Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type doublePair` of these really doesn't make sense. If the `snd` is always twice the `fst`, then it doesn't actually contain any information! So, this type is definitely better expressed as

```
newtype DoubleableInt = DoubleableInt {getDoubleableInt :: Int}
```

The others do make some sense, but I think you're still a bit missing the *point of an abstraction*. The type `validDDMMYYYY` is probably supposed to express a *date*, i.e. a point in time. How it *respresents* this shouldn't really be the user's concern: if a library depends on a certain representation, it should simply should offer specialised “smart constructors” to ensure well-formedness. Like

```
newtype AllIntsButZero = AllIntsButZero {getNonzeroInt :: Int}

mkNonzeroInt :: Int -> Maybe AllIntsButZero
mkNonzeroInt 0 = Nothing
mkNonzeroInt n = AllIntsButZero n
```

You may then refuse to export the `AllIntsButZero` constructor (which would allow users to form incorrect `AllIntsButZero 0`):

```
module RestrictedNumbers (AllIntsButZero, getNonzeroInt, mkNonzeroInt) where
```

This way, users will only see `AllIntsButZero` as a “black box”, and the *functions* they can use with it are guaranteed to yield well-formed values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm guessing i would still have to make checks via guards. I was hoping to make a 'closed type' where there are no operations that will lead to an 'invalid' value i.e. Nothing.

Comment: Yes, if you don't export the constructors then you can make a type “closed” in this sense allright. Just make sure all the functions you do export obey the invariances.