# How to create Type which contains String with limited length in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a type with restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978191/how-to-make-a-type-with-restrictions)

Is it possible in Haskell to create a type for example "Name" which is a String but containing no more then 10 letters?

If not how can I forbid to create a Person with to long name (where Person is defined like that: `data Person = Person Name`).

Maybe it is not important at all, maybe that kind of problems should be solved in Haskell in a different way?

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. The linked question is expressly general in purpose. It is only if you have dependent types on the brain that you will see *this* question as pertaining to them; user1376072 isn't asking how to put an arbitrary constraint on a type with a predicate, but how to construct a type subject to a specific invariant. Viewing the problem that way would be an inefficient mistake even if we had the capability in Haskell.

Comment: Even with the linked problem people failed to show enough Okasaki-like intelligence: there is a limit to the invariants you can impose on a Haskell type but we're nowhere near it with `user1376072` 's question. Even with dependent types you will still want to construct types with Okasaki like intelligence, not with crude types + crude predicates.

Comment: As an illustration of this dimness in a more complex case see e.g. the discussion here http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/06/well-founded-recursion-in-agda/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't export the constructor from the module where you define the type, and instead export a “smart constructor”:

```
module Name (Name(), -- exports the type Name, but not the data constructor Name
             nameFromString,
             stringFromName)
where

data Name = Name String

-- this is the only way to create a Name
nameFromString :: String -> Maybe Name
nameFromString s | 10 < length s = Nothing
                 | otherwise     = Just (Name s)

-- this is the only way to access the contents of a Name
stringFromName :: Name -> String
stringFromName (Name s) = s
```

---

So you're concerned that if you previously had code that didn't require names to be limited to ten characters, you can't just drop in `nameFromString` as it has type `String -> Maybe Name` instead of `String -> Name`.

First, if you really want to throw an exception, you can define

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

nameFromString' :: String -> Name
nameFromString' = fromMaybe (error "attempted to construct an invalid Name") . nameFromString
```

and use that instead.

Second, throwing an exception is sometimes the wrong thing to do. Consider

```
askUserForName :: IO Name
askUserForName
   = do putStr "What's your name? (10 chars max)  "
        s <- getLine
        case nameFromString s of
            Just n  -> return n
            Nothing -> askUserForName
```

Rewriting this to use exceptions would result in more complex code.

Comment: Your answer is brilliant. I'm still analyzing it (cause I got weak understanding of consequences of using "Maybe". For now i think that it brakes "open close principle" in the same way as Checked Exception do it in Java)

And now something completely different. You got a little mistake here: 10:31. Should be "10 < length s".

Comment: (Fixed mistake.) The Open/Closed principle doesn't apply, because the whole point of this Smart Constructor pattern is that all the smart constructors and all the smart deconstructors are in this single module. If you want to write another smart constructor for this type, you will have to modify this module: that's the point, that all direct uses of the constructor are in this module, so you can easily check they all do the right thing.

Comment: But if you got constructor which could not fail previously and you returned pure value (not "Maybe" value) from that constructor and now your constructor have to return "Maybe" value (cause your constructor fails in some situations now) you need to apply that Maybe value to all libraries which use previous constructor version. But maybe I don't understand something? And again something completely different. Maybe it 'll be reasonable to add to your example something like this: "stringFromMaybeName (Just(Name s)) = s" ? or it is a bad practice?

Comment: @user1376072 Are you kidding? It was you who wanted to forbid users to make a Name with more than 10 characters. But there are alternatives to Maybe: Be picky and terminate the program with error when the String is too long *or* Be easy and just tkae the 10 first characters of any String you are given. BTW, it is a bad idea in the first place to limit something to an arbitrary size.

Comment: @Ingo I'll rather ignore your very specific sense of humor. From your proposals one is just perfect for me: I'll should throw an exception. That's how I'll resolve that problem in Java. But I've read (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!) that this is a bad practice in hasskell. Is that true?

Comment: @user1376072 See my edit. But in general, if you think you will need to change the internals of a datatype, without editing client code, you shouldn't be allowing client code direct access to its constructors. Instead you must encapsulate it, e.g. behind a smart constructor.

Comment: @dave4420 again your answer was very helpful. I rewrote your example in a way that it throws exception, works fine for me. But I don't understand why you are afraid that code will be more complex. I think that it is a threat which may occur in a simple program in which you don't have dedicated layer or function to handle exceptions. When you have such function or layer it is more complex to bother with "Maybe" and such a stuff (because it may occur in various places). My opinion came from Java World but I thing that it is right in Haskell. Am I right?

Comment: You can't catch exceptions in pure code. So if your pure function throws an exception, I can't catch it without using `IO`. And we like to avoid `IO` where possible.

Comment: So I can choose between two ways of preventing creation invalid instances of some type: 1) "Maybe" or "Either" which for me behaves like Checked Exception in Java which violates "open close principle" (I'm sorry but I see no convincing arguments against this thesis)  2) Throwing an exception which cannot be handled in normal function. It looks bad.

Comment: As a beginner I must say that it looks bad for now ;)

Comment: @dave4420 Thank you very much this answers is much clearer than the one provided in the supossedly duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978191/how-to-make-a-type-with-restrictions

Answer (score 9):

dave4420 has the answer for what you *should* do.  That is, only export smart constructors.  In a dependently typed language you *could* limit data types to certain forms.  But, Haskell is not dependently typed.

Wait, no that is not true.  Haskell is "the worlds most popular dependently typed language".  You just have to fake the dependent types. Stop.  Read no further if you are 1. still learning basic Haskell 2. not totally insane.

It is possible to encode your "no longer than 10 characters" constraint in the type system.  with a type like

```
data Name where
    Name :: LessThan10 len => DList Char len -> Name
```

but I'm getting ahead of myself

first of all, you need tons of extensions (I assume GHC 7.4, early versions can still do it, but it is much more of a pain)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies,
             DataKinds,
             GADTs,
             FlexibleInstances,
             FlexibleContexts,
             ConstraintKinds-}

import Prelude hiding (succ)
```

now we build some machinery for type level naturals...using the new DataKinds extension

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type N1 = S Z --makes writing numbers easier
type N2 = S N1
--etc
type N10 = S N9
```

now we need a data representation of numbers and a way to generate them

```
data Natural n where
    Zero :: Natural Z
    Succ :: Natural a -> Natural (S a)

class Reify a where
   reify :: a

instance Reify (Natural Z) where
   reify = Zero

instance Reify (Natural n) => Reify (Natural (S n)) where
   reify = Succ (reify)
```

okay, now we can encode the idea of number being less than 10, and write a helper to test it for boot

```
type family LTE (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Bool
type instance LTE Z b = True
type instance LTE (S a) Z = False
type instance LTE (S a) (S b) = LTE a b

--YAY constraint kinds!
type LessThan10 a = True ~ (LTE a N10)

data HBool b where
   HTrue :: HBool True
   HFalse :: HBool False

isLTE :: Natural a -> Natural b -> HBool (LTE a b)
isLTE Zero _ = HTrue
isLTE (Succ _) Zero = HFalse
isLTE (Succ a) (Succ b) =  isLTE a b
```

with all of that we can define length encoded strings

```
data DList a len where
   Nil :: DList a Z
   Cons :: a -> DList a len -> DList a (S len)

toList :: DList a len -> [a]
toList Nil = []
toList (Cons x xs) = x:toList xs

data Name where
   Name :: LessThan10 len => DList Char len -> Name
```

and even get the string back, and define a neat-oh `Show` instance for `Name`

```
nameToString :: Name -> String
nameToString (Name l) = toList l

instance Show Name where
   show n = "Name: " ++ nameToString n
```

the problem is that we need a way to turn a `String` into a `Name`.  That is harder.

First up, lets figure out how long a String is

```
data AnyNat where
    AnyNat :: Natural n -> AnyNat

zero = AnyNat Zero
succ (AnyNat n) = AnyNat (Succ n)

lengthNat :: [a] -> AnyNat
lengthNat [] = zero
lengthNat (_:xs) = succ (lengthNat xs)
```

now it is a simple matter to turn lists into dependent lists

```
fromListLen :: Natural len -> [a] -> Maybe (DList a len)
fromListLen Zero [] = Just Nil
fromListLen Zero (x:xs) = Nothing
fromListLen (Succ a) [] = Nothing
fromListLen (Succ a) (x:xs) = do rs <- fromListLen a xs
                                 return (Cons x rs)
```

still not home free, but we are getting there

```
data MaybeName b where
    JustName :: LessThan10 len => DList Char len -> MaybeName True
    NothingName :: MaybeName False

maybeName :: MaybeName b -> Maybe Name
maybeName (JustName l) = Just $ Name l
maybeName (NothingName) = Nothing

stringToName' :: Natural len -> String -> MaybeName (LTE len N10)
stringToName' len str = let t = isLTE len (reify :: Natural N10)
                        in case t of
                           HFalse ->  NothingName
                           HTrue  -> case fromListLen len str of
                                          Just x -> JustName x
                                          --Nothing -> logic error
```

the last bit just involves convincing GHC we are not trying to blow the compiler's brains out `unsafePerformIO $ produce evilLaugh`

```
stringToNameLen :: Natural len -> String -> Maybe Name
stringToNameLen len str = maybeName $ stringToName' len str

stringToNameAny :: AnyNat -> String -> Maybe Name
stringToNameAny (AnyNat len) str = stringToNameLen len str

stringToName :: String -> Maybe Name
stringToName str = stringToNameAny (lengthNat str) str
```

wow, I write long stack overflow posts, but this takes the cake

we test it

```
*Main> stringToName "Bob"
Just Name: Bob
*Main> stringToName "0123456789"
Just Name: 0123456789
*Main> stringToName "01234567890"
Nothing
```

So it works, and the type system now can enforce the invariant that your names are no more than 10 characters.  Seriously though, odds are this is not worth your effort.

Comment: You should just wait for GHC 7.6 with its integrated type-level naturals, that will provide two thirds of this code pre-packaged, you'll just have to write the Name type and the conversion from String to Maybe Name... Still not worth it probably, compared to a simple smart constructor.

Comment: @Jedai we need compiler support for some things (certainly efficiency, but also cleaner notation, etc) but I would be pretty happy if we just had a neat type level natural numbers library that came with the platform

Comment: Sure that could have been a solution, but now it would be better to avoid doing that, given that we have a solution coming for the next release of GHC (with supports for literals in type). Most new people interested in the possibility should try to write against the API of these naturals rather than use one of the current libraries and have to rewrite next year.

Comment: The type system can enforce the invariant that names are no longer than 10 Chars long in infinitely many ways without extensions.

Answer (score 5):

You described the type perfectly well. You'll soon regret it of course...

```
data Name  = N1 Char
           | N2 Char Char
           | N3 Char Char Char
           | N4 Char Char Char Char
           | N5 Char Char Char Char Char
           | N6 Char Char Char Char Char Char
           | N7 Char Char Char Char Char Char Char
           | N8 Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char
           | N9 Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char
           | N10 Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char Char
           deriving (Show, Eq,Ord)

prettyName :: Name -> String
prettyName (N1 a) = a:[]
prettyName (N2 a b) = a:b:[]
prettyName (N3 a b c) = a:b:c:[]
prettyName (N4 a b c d) = a:b:c:d:[]
prettyName (N5 a b c d e) = a:b:c:d:e:[]
prettyName (N6 a b c d e f) = a:b:c:d:e:f:[]
prettyName (N7 a b c d e f g) = a:b:c:d:e:f:g:[]
prettyName (N8 a b c d e f g h) = a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:[]
prettyName (N9 a b c d e f g h i) = a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:[]
prettyName (N10 a b c d e f g h i j) = a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:[]
```

And while we're importing Text.PrettyPrint here in ghci, why not a parser?

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<*))
-- still lame
pN :: Parser Name
pN = do letters <- many1 alphaNum <* space
        case letters of 
            a:[]  -> return $ N1 a  
            a:b:[]  -> return $ N2 a b  
            a:b:c:[]  -> return $ N3 a b c  
            a:b:c:d:[]  -> return $ N4 a b c d  
            a:b:c:d:e:[]  -> return $ N5 a b c d e  
            a:b:c:d:e:f:[]  -> return $ N6 a b c d e f  
            a:b:c:d:e:f:g:[]  -> return $ N7 a b c d e f g  
            a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:[]  -> return $ N8 a b c d e f g h  
            a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:[]  -> return $ N9 a b c d e f g h i  
            a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:[]  -> return $ N10 a b c d e f g h i j
            _ -> unexpected "excess of letters"

-- *Main> parseTest pN "Louise "
-- N6 'L' 'o' 'u' 'i' 's' 'e'
-- *Main> parseTest pN "Louisiana "
-- N9 'L' 'o' 'u' 'i' 's' 'i' 'a' 'n' 'a'
-- *Main> parseTest (fmap prettyName pN) "Louisiana "
-- "Louisiana"
-- *Main> parseTest pN "Mississippi "
-- parse error at (line 1, column 13):
-- unexpected excess of letters
```

... Maybe this wasn't such a good idea ...

Comment: it doesn't have to be *that* bad

Comment: Och, your parser really needs left factoring...

Comment: Why? It may be useful if you try to define zip code or something like that.
Thanks for that answer. For a beginner it's very instructive.

Comment: sorry stephen, I was a little tipsy when I wrote this last night :)  I'll leave it since user1376072seems to have got something from it.

Comment: I improved the parser slightly.